# reference_wrapper: Is this UB?

Tags: c++

I'm curious if this code is UB.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/nU0iPLCrPXwQ7Kor

The code does not crash (in both GCC and Clang, with or without optimization), which makes me more and more baffled..

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    deque<int> l {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    vector<reference_wrapper<int>> v (l.begin(), l.end());
    // v now holds references to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in l

    cout << v[3] << '\n'; // 4

    l.pop_front();    // 1 popped

    for (auto num : l) {
        cout << num << ' '; // 2 3 4 5 
    }
    cout << '\n';    

    cout << v[0] << '\n';  // I think this should crash because 1 is dangling reference

    l.pop_front();  // 2 popped

    for (auto num : l) {
        cout << num << ' '; // 3 4 5
    }

    cout << '\n';    

    cout << v[1] << '\n';  // I think it should crash but it still outputs 2
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior does not imply that the program will or should crash. It is _undefined_ behavior.

Comment: Undefined behavior does not mean that your program will crash. This is an option, but literally any behavior is fine — that's why it's called undefined behavior. And yes, your code is UB.

Comment: It's called a "dangling reference" and accessing it is UB. See [cppref (bottom)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference). Undefined behaviour means "not defined in the standard". The actual behavior might be defined in the implementation,  but there are no guarantees. Things might break when you change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code does not crash is because you get lucky with regards to implementation details of deque.

A deque allocates memory in blocks of 512 byte. The first and last block in a deque can be partially filled at their front or back, respectively. Pointers mark these locations. A pop_front simply moves that pointer one element forward, as long as the first block does not become completely empty.

In your example, the complete content fits into one block. So you simply keep referencing memory that remains allocated and is just considered empty by the deque. Of course any operation such as push_front or any other resize may change that.

Comment: Also a compiler or compiler flag, which detects the UB and starts reasoning that this cannot be could lead to totally different code, even with this deque implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm curious if this code is UB.

Yes this is clearly undefined behavior due to using a dangling reference.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing is a result of undefined behavior.  But as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program could have resulted in segmentation fault.

The first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>